# Merge dataframes that have repetitive IDs on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have two dataframes :

```
    left = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "key": ["K0", "K0", "K1", "K2", "K2", "K3", "K4"],
        "A": ["A0", 2, "A1", "A2", 4, "A3", "A4"],
        "B": ["B0", 3, "B1", "B2", 4, "B3", "B4"],
    }
)
right = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "key": ["K0", "K0", "K1", "K2", "K3"],
        "C": ["C0", 5, "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", 7, "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    }
)

# table1 left
    key A   B
0   K0  A0  B0
1   K0  2   3
2   K1  A1  B1
3   K2  A2  B2
4   K2  4   4
5   K3  A3  B3
6   K4  A4  B4

# table2 right
    key C   D
0   K0  C0  D0
1   K0  5   7
2   K1  C1  D1
3   K2  C2  D2
4   K3  C3  D3
```

When I do the merge function (left join) of the two tables, I get :

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how="left", on="key")

    key A   B   C   D
0   K0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1   K0  A0  B0  5   7
2   K0  2   3   C0  D0
3   K0  2   3   5   7
4   K1  A1  B1  C1  D1
5   K2  A2  B2  C2  D2
6   K2  4   4   C2  D2
7   K3  A3  B3  C3  D3
8   K4  A4  B4  NaN NaN
```

While the result I want is something like this :

```
    key A   B   C   D
0   K0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1   K0  2   3   5   7
2   K1  A1  B1  C1  D1
3   K2  A2  B2  C2  D2
4   K2  4   4   C2  D2
5   K3  A3  B3  C3  D3
6   K4  A4  B4  NaN NaN
```

I really don't know how to approach this problem. Should I add suffixe to the IDs ?
I will be glad if someone can help me with this. Thanks you in advance.

(Note that my table does have some same IDs in different rows as they contain complementary informations)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try the following,

```
left['C'] = right['C']
left['D'] = right['D']
print(left)
```

### Output

```
key A   B   C   D
0   K0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1   K0  2   3   5   7
2   K1  A1  B1  C1  D1
3   K2  A2  B2  C2  D2
4   K2  4   4   C3  D3
5   K3  A3  B3  NaN NaN
6   K4  A4  B4  NaN NaN
```

Comment: Hey, thank you but this was a sample of the tables. I have two tables that have over 10,000 rows and some rows are skipped from one table to another so I have to merge it via the 'key' as reference.